# Limit the number of time a function can be used in a code base

Tags: c++, time, compilation, c-preprocessor

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a legacy function that is used exactly 3 times in our code base. I want to get rid of this function but it will require sometime. Meanwhile, I would like to prevent other developers to use the function elsewhere. Is there a way to enforce this at compile time e.g. with an error?

Any ideas?

**Update:** I forgot to mention that my function resides in a namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put it in headers, to start with.  Locally declare it in the .c file so that it's not as publically visible.

You could then do this as well:

public_header.h:

```
     #define my_function(arg1, arg2, ...) exit(128)
```

And in the .cpp file that actually needs to use it:

```
     #undef my_function
     int my_function(int arg1, char *arg2, ...);
```

Comment: Other solutions provide a compile time warning, instead of a brutal exit.

Comment: Hey, you want to discourage them right?  I was tempted to suggest a sleep(4000);

Comment: @tibur: Just change the #define into something that will not compile (then you get an error: even better). I would also add `extern` to the declaration.

Comment: I guess `#define my_function(arg1, arg2, ...) #error "Don't use that please" would be much better.

Comment: I actually tried that....  You can't use a #error in a #define (which doesn't surprise me).

Comment: This looks like a good solution but what about if the function is in a namespace?

Comment: Actually, if your compiler is MSVC than you can use the __pragma keyword [Pragma Directives and the __Pragma Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx). For example the following code errors out.`#define ERROR_OUT __pragma(message("error: dont do this"))`. And later in the code you write ERROR_OUT. The ':' after the 'error' is important, and that's what makes the message an error and stops the compilation. Note tested with VS 2010.

Answer (score 4):

For gcc you can use "deprecated" attribute.

```
int old_fn () __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

This will emit warning every time function used somewhere.

Comment: Actually I would like this warning to appear on the fourth use of the function. Is it possible?

Comment: but then, you get the warning also for the current uses. Thus `-Werror` cannot be activated any longer.

Comment: Just mix and match... use the deprecated attribute and disable the warning in the three cases where you need it with a pragma directive (I think that is possible, never tried that particular warning) It will warn and it will also tell you where the uses are.

Comment: Or just rename the original function (eg. `original_function()` ) without deprecated attribute. Then create a new function with the name of the original function (like `function() __attribute__ ((deprecated)) { original_function(); }` ), make it deprecated and call the function with a new name. Then fix those 3 occurrences to use your renamed function (`original_function()`). The existing code will compile without complaining but if someone uses the deprecated function it complains.

Answer (score 1):

As part of C++ no.

There are tricks, of course.

One such trick is to declare the function as locally as possible near the current point of use.

- Simply declaring it at the top of the source file use it, right below the includes
- Declaring it (and defining it) as `static` at the top of the source file that use it, better for visibility but implies duplication

It security by obscurity, not reknown for being that great, but I would deem it acceptable in this case (with a fat comment on top of the function).

Other solutions include `#pragma warning` in the header (not nice) or the `deprecated` attribute, but this will cause warnings for the current uses, this can be problematic (pollutes build output). And if people are not bothered with warnings for the current use, they won't bother for new warnings either, not a good habit to get into!

Now, there are other solutions.

You could simply write a hook that scan the sources files and count the number of occurrences.

```
grep -r "deprecated_func" include src | wc -l
```

This hook can be integrated either as part of the build process or as a pre-commit hook in your version system. Be sure to lower the number of allowed occurrences as soon as you get rid of one function.

*Note: you can also use the `deprecated` attribute with a filter on the compiler output. But this does not count for `-Werror`.*

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question! This got me thinking whether a combination of boost preprocessor's [BOOST_PP_COUNTER](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html) and [BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) (or C++0x's static_assert) would work. One big problem is every time I look into Boost.Preprocessor library, it makes my head spin :)

At the end, what I would like to write is 
`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(BOOST_PP_COUNTER <= 3);`

I don't have time to test my ideas right now, but hopefully this might lead to something. I won't be able to test my ideas until the weekend though...